# foreign key serialization drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i created a model named 'Post'.
here is the code:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date']
```

i want to get all objects of Post model with **users firstname and lastname**.

in views.py:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def allPost(request):
    allpost = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializers(allpost, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

in serialisers.py:

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

class PostSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.RelatedField(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a serialzier with firstname and lastname:

```
class SimpleUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name')
```

and then use that serializer as subserialiser:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = SimpleUserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user')
```

This generates a JSON blob like:

```
{
    "body": "Sample body text",
    "date": "2020-12-11T12:34:56.789Z",
    "user": {
        "first_name": "MyFirst",
        "last_name": "MyLast"
    }
}
```

or you use make use of two `CharField`s:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    first_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.first_name', read_only=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(source='user.last_name', read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date')
```

this generates as JSON blob:

```
{
    "body": "Sample body text",
    "date": "2020-12-11T12:34:56.789Z",
    "first_name": "MyFirst",
    "last_name": "MyLast"
}
```

---

> **Note**: The name of a serializer class is normally *singular*, so `PostSerializer` instead of
> <s>`PostSerializers`</s>.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use related field in this case. **many=True** should be used if you're passing multiple objects (like you did with posts).

What you should do is user your **UserSerializer** in **PostSerializer**

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('body','date','user')
```

Read docs for more info
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Comment: it works, but it also shows hashed password. is it safe?

Comment: It's just the example, of course it's better to customize UserSerializer and return only the fields you need. It's almost not possible to unhash password, but better practice is not to return it.